# Changing the background color of ::selection

Tags: javascript, css, selection

How can I select the `::selection` element using JavaScript in order to apply style rules?

```
document.querySelector("::selection").style.backgroundColor = "red";

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null(…)
```

Comment: Do you mean the selection of text or something else?

Comment: @Rayon how can I add a class to the `::selection` element? The answer from the 'duplicate' question doesn't seem to be applicable here...

Comment: @BIlalKhan yes, the CSS `::selection` selector. Obviously I can't give this a class as the 'duplicate' suggests as it isn't an actual element.